# (Windows) Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, windows, connection, popsql

I see that is question is asked a lot, but I cannot find solutions for Windows but only for Ubuntu. I amtrying to follow an sql tutorial, so I installed everything but I keep getting this error.

> Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

The server service is running and I am not sure where to start. I also cannot find the file mysql.nfc that I thought I needed....
Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the Connection Type to local: [Edit your connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmuHw.png).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).